# Access Exchange or Office 365 API using Meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ms-office, office365, exchange-server-2010

Currently I am using Exchange 2010 to manage our calendars. I believe that there is an API available for Exchange that allows editing of most calendars and aspects of the calendar. I want to build a Meteor JS app that interfaces with the Exchange 2010 to retrieve and edit the calendars. Meteor JS is just a javascript framework, so if you know how to access the API with javascript, you should be able to help me answer the following questions.

What is the best way to build a Meteor JS app (or just use javascript) to interface with the Exchange 2010 to retrieve and edit the calendars?

Are there any tutorials on how to get it working?

Also, if I upgrade to Office 365, will the APIs be the same?

Comment: Have you tried looking for node.js packages?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to look for node.js packages but did not find anything suitable. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I just wanted to make sure that you was aware that 'ordinary' nodejs packages could be used :-/ sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am not familiar with Meteor JS, I can provide you general API info for Exchange.  For Exchange 2010, there is a SOAP API called Exchange Web Services (EWS) and this has rich calendar functionality.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.140).aspx) for EWS documentation, and there are also concept articles on [how to create/modify meetings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877049(v=exchg.140).aspx) and hot to get a [user's availability information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa494212(v=exchg.140).aspx).  For Office 365, we have an [Office 365 Calendar REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn792114(v=office.15).aspx) that should provide the calendar related functionality you need.

Please let me know if you have any questions or need more info.

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: I have taken a look, and it seems that the Office 365 API is much easier to implement, especially since I can use JavaScript to do it. Now I am wondering how I can communicate to my web application that an event has been created or edited. Is there some way to trigger a call to my web app when my Office 365 Calendar is updated? I added a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372752/office-365-calendar-api-trigger-call-to-app-based-on-creating-event

Comment: I just answered your question.  We don't yet have notifications support, but are looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no javascript API for Exchange. For Office 365 there is a preview API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892(v=office.15).aspx

Use a caldav Server like SabreDav http://sabre.io and a outlook plugin like http://www.bynari.net/.

The caldav server can be accessed with the official caldav api (xml,http requests) So you don´t need any deeper knowledge of php.

This way you could support even more clients.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean after your first paragraph. Are you suggesting I use some extra plugins for Exchange 2010?

Comment: No, not a plugin for exchange. A plugin for your outlook clients. Microsoft removed caldav support with Outlook 2010. The bynari client is very easy to install and not very expensive. SabreDav is a free open source server for php. The byari client communicates with it. The Office API is in a very early state and you may run into problems.