# Office 365 Calendar API trigger call to app based on creating event

Tags: javascript, meteor, ms-office, office365, office365-apps

Whenever an event gets created or edited in the Calendar, I would like the Office 365 Calendar API to notify my web application (written in Meteor JS and JavaScript). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your question and interest in Office 365 REST APIs!  We currently don't have support for notifications but this is ranked high on our roadmap and we are looking into it.  Please let me know if you have any questions or need more info.

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: I should add that you still can use the old EWS streaming notifications, if this is an important requirement and you don't mind dealing with XML/SOAP requests. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_eventtypes